# Accessing collection of reactions after awaitReaction node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, collections, discord.js

The code below works well, until I try to send the messages after either an X or check is selected. I get this instead https://i.gyazo.com/2b8c4cfcd047121df364218ef0e8d7e9.png

My understanding is that this collection is a map. I have tried various ways of accessing a map and all have been either undefined or [object object] etc... instead of the username of the person who sent the reaction that was collected. According to the docs, reaction.users is how I think the collections is accessed, but it isn't working for me...

I know it acknowledged who sent the reaction, because I added the line "message.reply('You accepted the challenge.')" right above the message.channel.send(`${reaction.users}..." line, and it does reply with that line immediately after I react and it does display the username correctly. I have tried using collection.get() like I've seen some people use, that doesn't work either... I cannot progress further for my bot without getting this to work.

I require the username, id, etc.. for the user who reacted, because their info is used to submit them into a mysql table that holds the stats for the game this challenge is for.

```
async function acceptQuestion() {

  const agree = "✅"
  const disagree = "❌"
  let msg = await message.channel.send(`A challenge has been issued by ${author}?\n\n**IF** you are listed above, please select one of the following to accept or deny the challenge...`)
  await msg.react(agree)
  await msg.react(disagree)

  const filter = (reaction, user) => {
  return ['✅', '❌'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && uniquePlayersIDArray.includes(user.id);

  };
 const collector = await msg.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });

  collector.on('collect', (reaction, reactionCollector) => {

  console.log(`Collected ${reaction.emoji.name}`)

  if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
  message.channel.send(`${reaction.user} has **accepted** the challenge! Please await 5 minutes to pass or for all challenged players to respond!`)
  } else if (reaction.emoji.name === '❌') {
  message.channel.send(`${reaction.user} has **declined* the challenge! Please await 5 minutes to pass or for all challenged players to respond!`)
    }
    });

    collector.on('end', collected => {
    console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
    });
    }
```

As I said above, instead of [object map] I want to get the username of the person who sent the reaction. I will also need to get the id for the user as well. Nothing I try has worked.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of `reaction.user` you'll need to use [MessageReaction.users](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction?scrollTo=users) which will give a collection of all the users who reacted to the message. Then you can get the [first user](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=first) from the collection and get his/her name.

Some example code (this isn't tested but should get you in the right direction):

```js
collector.on('collect', (reaction, reactionCollector) => {
    console.log(`Collected ${reaction.emoji.name}`)

    let firstUser = reaction.users.filter(user => !user.bot).first();

    if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
        message.channel.send(`${firstUser.username} has **accepted** the challenge! Please await 5 minutes to pass or for all challenged players to respond!`)
    } else if (reaction.emoji.name === '❌') {
        message.channel.send(`${firstUser.username} has **declined* the challenge! Please await 5 minutes to pass or for all challenged players to respond!`)
    }
});
```

Comment: I'll have to play around with it, because instead of giving the username of the first person to react, it gives the username of the bot. I think the collection is picking up the second reaction the bot places on the message (the red X)... despite the filter supposedly ignoring it... https://i.gyazo.com/deea3f2ee591056e2f7e9cca2463e355.png

Any ideas how to get past that?

Comment: @Zarvix I've updated my answer. I've added a filter to the array which removes all the bot users before grapping the first item

Comment: That worked great! Except for one thing I needed to change, instead of .first(), I did .last(), because I'll have multiple people accepting the challenge not just a single user. I assume (so I might be wrong), that each additional reaction will be added to the bottom of the collection, so the newest reaction should be the one I grab. Is that a fair assumption? It worked for me that way anyway, even reversing the order of the two players reactions in accept. I know .last() and .first() can take into account the usedID of the players, so I didn't know if that was the same case here too.

Comment: It is correct indeed that the newst reaction will be added at the end of the array, so .last() should do the trick